# What happened to Burke in "Harry Potter"?

Tags: harry-potter

We meet Borgin, but Burke is only even mentioned once, where is he all the time, what happened to him? He is never stated to be dead, maybe You-Know-Who killed him as a loose end, but that would probably come up.

What happened to him?

Comment: All they found of him was a withered old hand that lets you see in the dark.

Comment: https://harrypotter.fandom.com/wiki/Caractacus_Burke

Answer (score 8):

Dumbledore refers to him in the past tense in [*Harry Potter and the Half-Blood Prince*](https://harrypotter.fandom.com/wiki/Harry_Potter_and_the_Half-Blood_Prince). The clear *implication* is that he's dead, but there's no solid confirmation in any of the books or (as far as I'm aware) any of the supporting materials or interviews to offer any specifics on the how or the when.

> Dumbledore gave the Pensieve an extra-vigorous shake and Caractacus Burke descended back into the swirling mass of memory whence he had come.
>   ‘He only gave her ten Galleons?’ said Harry indignantly.
>   **‘Caractacus Burke was not famed for his generosity,’ said Dumbledore.**

Comment: Yeah, very little info on him. He was part of the [Sacred Twenty-Eight](https://www.pottermore.com/writing-by-jk-rowling/pure-blood) so his family, like the other pure-blood families, may well have been picky about who they bred with and dying off as a result.